# SIM800L AT+CSQ return 0,0 when SIM is inserted and 20~40 when I insert the sim

Tags: gsm, sim800

I have SIM800L module,

when I try AT+CSQ it returns 0,0

when I tried to remove the sim and try again it returns number, 0 (25,0)

and I cannot register to a network

so AT+CREG? returns 0,2

should I activate something or do another command before trying to do CSQ or either connect to a network..

when I try: AT+COPS=?

it lists all networks available, but cannot connect to any of them

thank you

Comment: Try upgrsding the sim's firmware

Comment: I did, 
I got the same result :( no luck

Comment: AT+CSMINS? To check whether it can find sim inserted

Comment: I hope you are using a 2G ready sim.

Comment: the result of at+csmins? is: +CSMINS: 0,1
.
and Iam using a M2M card. and I called the provider, they told me that the card is 2g/3g card !

Comment: Does that card work in your handset?

Comment: Yes it woks :( .

Comment: I found something that the module always send these       : +CFUN: 1

+CPIN: READY

Call Ready

SMS Ready

as loop

Comment: Your SIM800 modules is resetting. See the power supply section of datasheet

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, it was from the power it takes.
when the module is trying to connect to a network it consumes a lot of power, so I lower down the resistor.

now it is stable and connect smoothly.

try to check your module datasheet and check the power consumption

Comment: Congratulation on realizing that power issues were to blame, as they often are for these.  However a fixed "resistor" does not belong in the power supply circuitry of this module. If you are using one, you are taking a horribly mistaken approach.  Even engineering a suitable *voltage regulator* is enough of a challenge that many projects just run these off the single cell they were designed to use in their original life as limited-feature mobile phones.