# SIM 800L, I lose signal (+CSQ=0,0) once I insert the SIM card

Tags: sim, gprs

I have a GSM/GPRS module, SIM800L, and I am facing network difficulties with it.

If the SIM card is *not* inserted, the antenna connects perfectly to the network with `+CSQ=0,16`.  However, once I insert the SIM card, I lose network connection and `+CSQ=0,0`.

Comment: Welcome to EE!  Your SIM may be limiting which operator is being used; try the "AT+COPS?" command in both cases.

Comment: It returned: +COPS = 0

Comment: With the SIM, I assume.  And without?

Comment: Yes, with the sim inserted , it returns 0

Comment: @Imene - Hi, As pointed out in the [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/340021) where you tried to ask this, but written as a (now-deleted) answer, the solution there was found to be related to the power supply, as it often is for these symptoms. You obviously saw that question, so please edit _your_ question here to explain: How did you confirm that your problem is _not_ with your power supply source / wiring i.e. how is your solution not the same as that previous question? What test equipment did you use (ideally an oscilloscope) to view the power waveform during net attach?

Comment: maybe you are getting a good signal from a nearby tower ... then you insert a SIM card and force a connection to another tower